# How to add more than 16 blocks in a section in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am building a new page for team members. made new section for it, and try to add a team member on the panel, but can't add more than 16.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See my update, Shopify last week increased the limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, 16 is a hard limit set by Shopify. The only way around it is to utilise the same section multiple times on the page.

EDIT: Shopify last week increased the limit from 16 to 50 blocks per section and increased 20 sections to 25 sections per page.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen, you could add more than 16 blocks in one section but do not know exactly how many limited blocks. I have not found related document yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can add more than 16 blocks in shopify by providing max_blocks  . please use this code into your section liquid file you want add these block.

```
{%- if section.blocks.size > 0 -%}
  <ul class="brand-carousel section-padding ">
    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
      <li class="item ">
        {%- if block.settings.link != blank -%}
          <a href="{{ block.settings.link }}">
        {%- endif -%}

          {%- if block.settings.image != blank -%}
            {{ block.settings.image | img_url| img_tag: block.settings.image.alt }}
          {%- else -%}
            {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
          {%- endif -%}

        {%- if block.settings.link != blank -%}
          </a>
        {%- endif -%}
      </li>
    {%- endfor -%}
  </ul>
{%- endif -%}



{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Custom image list",
  "class": "index-section",
  "max_blocks": 16,
  "settings": [
    {
      "type": "text",
      "id": "title",
      "label": "Heading",
      "default": "Logo list"
    }
  ],
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "logo_image",
      "name": "image",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "image_picker",
          "id": "image",
          "label": "Image"
        },
        {
          "type": "url",
          "id": "link",
          "label": "Link",
          "info": "Optional"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Custom image list",
      "category": "Image",
      "blocks": [
        {
          "type": "logo_image"
        },
        {
          "type": "logo_image"
        },
        {
          "type": "logo_image"
        },
        {
          "type": "logo_image"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Comment: This wouldn't do anything except set the same limit that Shopify had already imposed.

Comment: Yes Shopify has now increased blocks limit

Comment: Yes, but regardless, your code still would not do anything.

Comment: I have updated my pervious code, you need to use for this any where your created section template

Comment: I think you've misunderstood something, OP wants to use more blocks than what Shopify allow. Your code doesn't do that, it limits the number of blocks that can be used.

Comment: You can define max_blocks value upto 50